# Sharing a video in a video conference call

Tags: meetings, presentations, online

I have an interesting question. My company and a client will be having a meeting over Skype for business. I have prepared some videos that I would like to show at the meeting. I would like to stream these videos to the clients so that we can watch the videos at the same time. I would also like to "control" what everyone is seeing in terms of the video. For example, if I need to pause the video to explain a certain part to everyone.

I am aware that skype for business can kinda let you do this if you embed the video in a powerpoint. The only issue is that the file size must be below 25 MB. The video that I am playing is about 6 min long at 1080p resolution. The file size is 1.4 GB.

Also, we did try share screen for a different presentation once before and it was bad. The video was super choppy and horribly to watch. So that is out of the options

So, I am unable to use the skype for business solution. I was wondering, what does everyone else do in a situation like this? Is there some other solution that I can take? Is there some online solution that would allow me to upload to video to and give everyone a link and I can present it to them this way? Or should is something like this not possible?

Comment: Upload it to a company account on some video streaming service? Most of them allow making videos private, so you can only access them if you know the url.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is better suited to software recommendations SE.

Comment: You can look into Handbrake to get a 6 minute 1080p video to much more reasonable size. And if you're willing to accept some compression artifacts and slightly lower resolution, <20 MB for 6 minutes is easy to reach.

Comment: Agree with @MaskedMan - possible migration to another SE site but don't know which off the top of my head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are specifically asking for alternatives to Skype for Business, there are plenty of other options out there.  I've attended a number of webinars where the host was using either GoToWebinar or WebEx, however there are other screen sharing solutions such as JoinMe, AnyMeeting or GoToMeeting.  Some are free, others are expensive - depends what you want to achieve really.

Showing a video should work fine using these services.  However, I would consider down-scaling the video to 720p or lower quality as full HD over reduced bandwidth could lead to low quality playback if your clients have a slower connection.

Comment: I wouldn't mind doing that but the client needs to use Skype for business because that is what is installed on their end and they have some weird contract

Comment: But if you go to a webinar method, nothing needs to be installed on their PC?  Given the limitations you're facing when using SfB, it's clearly not an option. So you need a different method.  Also, this stack is for workplace-related issues, whereas this question is more about asking for software recommendations - so this question will most likely be closed.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you share your screen with Skype for Business?

That would be the best option. Get the video player to full screen and share your screen. Before doing so close any other software you have open.

Comment: Hello, we already tried that and the video quality was extremely poor. The video was super choppy